# Get length of Future var in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using [shared_preferences package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save my object. When I load my app I get the previous teams I created. If I don't get anything (first time) I create 2 default teams
This is what I've got:

```
Future<Null> _getTeams() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.get("teams") ??
      [
        {"name": "Team 2", "avatar": "assets/images/draw1.jpg"},
        {"name": "Team 3", "avatar": "assets/images/draw2.jpg"},
      ];
}

class MyState extends State<TeamsPage> {
  final _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  Future<List<Map>> _teams = _getTeams();
```

The problem comes when my widget needs to display dynamically these teams. They are not ready yet being a `Future` variable so I get an error with length and index:

```
child: AnimatedList(
                key: _listKey,
                initialItemCount: _teams.length,
                itemBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
                  return _buildItem(_teams[index], index, animation);
                },
              ),
```

With `index` I get this error:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future>'. Try
>   defining the operator '[]'

and with `length`:

> The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'Future>'

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a Future> or whatever type team has.
As this method is async you have to use await to work with its result.

```
Future<List<Team>> _getTeams() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.get("teams") ??
      [
        {"name": "Team 2", "avatar": "assets/images/draw1.jpg"},
        {"name": "Team 3", "avatar": "assets/images/draw2.jpg"},
      ];
}

var teams = await _getTeams();
```

If you did not define a type for team use List> as generic type in the future. You can then access its content by:

```
var teams = await _getTeams();
var firstTeamName = teams[0]['name'];
```

Comment: not sure how to make the class async: `class MyState extends State<TeamsPage> {
  final _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  var teams = await _getTeams();`

Comment: Do not fetch your state at field initialization time. The method initState() is available exactly for this use case. Override it and make it async.

Comment: Sorry for these noob questions (I just jumped into Flutter), but is not `initState()` a method that triggers when the widget is created? If so, wouldn't be better to load this *before* my widget loads?

Comment: initState is for the initial creation of the state. IMHO this is the right place to load stored preferences or default init the state. If you want to load it earlier, you have to create a scoped model to hold your data and trigger a reload of the widget when the data changes.

Comment: Think so... I was reading this and apparently there is nothing that loads before: https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle but I also get an issue when I convert the `initState` to async: `it's must be a void method without an async keyword`
```
class MyState extends State<TeamsPage> {
  final _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  List<Map> _teams = [];

initState() async {  
Future<List<Map>> _getTeams() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  ...
}
  _teams = await _getTeams();
}
```

Comment: The compiler takes this without error/warning.'''class MyState extends State<TeamsPage> { 
  final _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>(); 
  List<Team> _teams = []; 
  initState() async { 
    
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _teams = await _getTeams(); 
      } 

  Future<List<Team>> _getTeams() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.get("teams") ??
      [
        Team(name: "Team 2", avatar: "assets/images/draw1.jpg"),
        Team(name: "Team 3", avatar: "assets/images/draw2.jpg"),
      ];
}
}

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I have, but when I load my page: MyState.initState() returned a Future.

State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.

Comment: I got rid of that issue moving the async function outside. `InitState` cannot be async so I just called the function from it. But now I get a different one with `List<dynamic>` is not a subtype of type `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>`

Comment: I think it was related with the type I was using for `_teams`. I changed `<List<Map>>` to `List` and it's... "fine". The next problem is related to `RangeError` so something between this async function and the list widget. I tried another option, which is the localStorage library and this works without issues

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didn't work for me. I found [this doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data) useful from the official website.
One strategy for resolving this is by using the [**FutureBuilder** Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

So you get something like this

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
  future: _teams,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return AnimatedList(
            key: _listKey,
            initialItemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
              return _buildItem(snapshot.data[index], index, animation);
            },
          );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

You can pass the "*_team*" as "*snapshot.data*" to sub Widgets which require lists to work.